# How to get UIlabel to automatically span multiple lines dynamically. Inside a Tableview cell / ContentView with multiple UIlabels

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, interface-builder

We have the following UI in Xcode using IB. Essentially there is a TableView. The TableView has four rows inside the Content View - these are not table rows.

```
-- TableView
    -- StackView
        -- DateLabel (Row 1)
        -- StackView - Time and Category (Row 2)
              -- Timelabel
              -- Category label
        -- CategoryDetailLabel (Row 3)
        -- MoreLabel (Row 4)
```

We want the UILabel (CategoryDetailLabel) in Row 3 to expand dynamically based on the content. So based on documentation here we turned on the "Row Height" and "Estimated Height" on the TabelView to be automatic.

[image]

But Unfortunately only one row (line) gets displayed
[image]

When we change the row height on tableview to 150 we get all the rows to display

[image]

But the CategoryDetaillabel does not expand its height. The content gets truncated.
[image]

We have set the "Lines" of CategoryDetailLabel to 0. How do we fix this using IB.

Comment: Hi Jack, let me know if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Constraint the UILabel to all edges of the cell.

2 - add this code to your table view.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

3 - don't use a height for row.

Comment: And be sure to set the `numberOfLines` property of the label to 0, so that it adjusts dynamically to the amount of text to be displayed.